# Using LINQ to check for anything in a list that is not null or blank

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ to filter down my list and only contain values that actually have data in a certain string field.

I have it working for looking for a specific value as below:

```
 filteredProductsList = filteredProductsList.FindAll(s => s.repeatable.Equals("1"));
```

However, how can I change this so it looks for anything that has a value contained within the string. It could either be "" or null and these are the values I want to remove.

Comment: "It could either be "" or null and these are the values I want to remove." how can an empty string contain a `1` ? sorry but I am confused

Comment: `s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.repeatable)`? Or `s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.repeatable)`

Comment: `filteredProductsList = filteredProductsList.Where(product => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.repeatable));`

Comment: Sweet thankyou. @MongZhu sorry it was badly worded. I was showing how I have it working looking for a specific value. But wanted it to instead omit any blank or null values as shown above

Comment: Where does this query run? In memory list, or on the database?

Comment: FYI, `FindAll` is not Linq - it's a method of the `List<T>` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filteredProductsList = filteredProductsList.Where
  (s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.repeatable));
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need LINQ for it, You can use List.RemoveAll() - It removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_RemoveAll_System_Predicate__0__)

```
filteredProductsList.RemoveAll(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.repeatable));
```

Answer (score 0):

also, you can use **object.Equals** in your query it will fix null checking

```
object.Equals(objA, objB)
```

os the filter will be like this

```
filteredProductsList = filteredProductsList.FindAll(s => object.Equals(s.repeatable, "1"));
```